# Getting the response twice from server in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I am working on a mern app and currently working on the dashboard part of it , now the problem is i am getting some data from my express server but the problem is my server runs only once but when i console log my react code i can see that it se getting data twice , once the object is empty and in the next response i get the whole data, this creating a serious problem because i append that in my redux as soon as i get it from server and when i use that data in another component i get undefined and the code breaks , because it doesn't wait for the second response and throws error on the first one. Now i dont know what type of problem is but here is my code:-
Private route code:-

```
import React, { Component ,useEffect} from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {Navigate, Route , useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home/Home';
import Landing_page from './login_and_reg/Landing_page/Landing_page';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {action} from '../state/index'

const Protected_routes = () => {
    const Navigate = useNavigate();
    const auth_check = useSelector(state => state.auth)
    const data_check = useSelector(state => state.data)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {auth_checking,user_data} = bindActionCreators(action,dispatch)


    const private_routes = async() =>{
        const res = await fetch('/getdata',{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'x-auth-token':localStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        })
        const data = await res.json();
        if(data.status == 201){
            {auth_checking('true')}
            user_data(data.userdata)
        }
        else{
            {auth_checking('false')}
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        private_routes()
    },[])

    console.log({auth_check})
    console.log('this is the data i get from express',data_check)
    if (auth_check=='true') {
            return <Home/>  
    } 
    else {
        return <Landing_page/> 
        }        
    
}

export default Protected_routes

    
        useEffect(()=>{
            private_routes()
        },[])
    
        console.log({auth_check})
        console.log('this is the data i get from express',data_check)
        if (auth_check=='true') {
                return <Home/>  
        } 
        else {
            return <Landing_page/> 
            }        
        
    }
    
    export default Protected_routes
```

here is the photo from console:-
[image]

server side code:-

```
const authToken = async(req,res,next)=>{
  try{
    const authHeader = req.headers['x-auth-token']
    const verified = jwt.verify(authHeader, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    const user_data = await user.find({_id:verified.id})
    const final_data = {first_name:user_data[0].first_name,second_name:user_data[0].second_name,date:user_data[0].date,gender:user_data[0].gender}
    req.user_data = final_data
    
    next();

  }
  catch(err){
    res.status(400).json({message:'not right',status:400});
    console.log(err)
  }
  
}

app.post('/getdata' , authToken,(req,res) =>{
  
  res.status(201).json({message:'authorized',status:201,userdata:req.user_data});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are under a misconception here.

Your component code will get executed multiple times before you get data from the server.

The first time your component is mounted your code will get executed, this means that your code:

```
if (auth_check=='true') {
   return <Home/>  
} 
else {
   return <Landing_page/> 
}
```

gets executed way before you get an answer from your server.

There are multiple ways of fixing this:

1. you can add a new state that keeps track of if you got an answer to your server `const [hasResponse, setHasResponse] = useState(false)`. And call `setHasResponse` from inside `private_routes`.
2. You can restructure your entire code, make the auth request before loading the React app and load if after you are sure that a user is logged in or not.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with synchronisation of the code ? I just have to find a different way to get the solution like put an if condition and only append data when its not empty right?

Comment: Also i understand that my code will run way before getting anything from the server and that's why my first response is false but why there are two "true" responses? You can see in my screenshot

Comment: You are calling 2 different updates here auth_checking('true') user_data(data.userdata). This will trigger 2 different re-renders. One with auth_checking set to true, but old user_data and another one when auth_checking is true and data in user_data. From what I remember react doesn't guarantee batching multiple updates, so you're getting 2 different updates there.